# Obtain email or row with IF

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, filter, match, vlookup

I have a list of emails and information like this:

[image]

To take an example let's focus in yellow rows so each institution has their own area and the corresponding person to it, now the second part each person has a percentage, what I'm trying to do is I have a table with this percentage for each ID institution, if one are has less than 0.8 give me the email, something like this:

```
=IF(C2<=0.8, "mail1@mail.com", "")
```

Like this image:

[image]

In column J:N is the expected result I was trying with this formula:

```
=IF(C2<=0.8,(FILTER(Email!$D$2:$D$12,Email!$A$2:$A$24=B2,$D$2:$D$12<>""),""), "NO")
```

But no results!

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CLsmVqIRQ6iPG8B5_Rl7xdWr_yIIxsPmRJ4vUEAHwR4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(Email!A2:E, IFNA(VLOOKUP(Email!A2:A&Email!C2:C, 
 SPLIT(FLATTEN(Condition!B2:B&Condition!C1:F1&"×"&Condition!C2:F), "×"), 2, 0))<=0.8))
```

[image]

---

### Update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(Email!A2:E, IFNA(VLOOKUP(Email!A2:A&Email!C2:C, 
 SPLIT(FLATTEN(Condition!B2:B&Condition!C1:F1&"×"&Condition!C2:F), "×"), 2, 0))<=0.8, 
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(Email!A2:A&Email!C2:C, 
 SPLIT(FLATTEN(Condition!B2:B&Condition!C1:F1&"×"&Condition!C2:F), "×"), 2, 0))<>""))
```

[image]

Comment: Actually it works but in some cases where there is no value like institute 3 in Area 3 is empty so that shouldn't be included

Comment: So basically the light green should not be included in the function